# How to add to the datelist? it's overwrite. How can I solve it?

Tags: java, for-loop

How to add to the date list? it's overwrite. How can I solve it?

```
 List<LeaveDetails> leaveList=leaveDetailsService.getleavedatetesting(3);  
 List<Date> datelist = new ArrayList<Date>();  
 System.out.println("leave list is --> "+leaveList.toString()); 
 for (LeaveDetails lds: leaveList){  
    Date startd = new Date();  
    startd= lds.getStartDate();  

    Date endd = new Date();  
    endd = lds.getEndDate();  

    System.out.println("start date is ---> "+startd);  
    System.out.println("end date is ---> "+endd);  

    for (int i = startd.getDate() ; i<=(endd.getDate()+1);i++){     
        startd.setDate(i);  
        datelist.add(startd);       
        System.out.println(i+"--datelist ---> "+datelist.toString());     
    }  
}  
System.out.println("date list is ---> "+datelist.toString());
```

I want the list like this including startdate and enddate-->example date 2,3,4,8,9,10,11.
    In console, I got this,

```
     start date is ---> 2015-12-02    
     end date is ---> 2015-12-04    

    2--datelist ---> [2015-12-02]    
    3--datelist ---> [2015-12-03, 2015-12-03]    
    4--datelist ---> [2015-12-04, 2015-12-04, 2015-12-04]    
    5--datelist ---> [2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05] 

    start date is ---> 2015-12-08   
    end date is ---> 2015-12-11  

    8--datelist ---> [2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-08]  
    9--datelist ---> [2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-    09, 2015-12-09]  
    10--datelist ---> [2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-10, 2015-12-10, 2015-12-10]  
    11--datelist ---> [2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-11, 2015-12-11, 2015-12-11, 2015-12-11]  
    12--datelist ---> [2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-12, 2015-12-12, 2015-12-12, 2015-12-12, 2015-12-12]  

    date list is ---> [2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-05, 2015-12-12, 2015-12-12, 2015-12-12, 2015-12-12, 2015-12-12]    

    -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this loop:

```
for (int i = startd.getDate() ; i<=(endd.getDate()+1);i++){     
    startd.setDate(i);  
    datelist.add(startd);       
    System.out.println(i+"--datelist ---> "+datelist.toString());     
}
```

You're adding a reference to the same `Date` object several times, and mutating it on each iteration. You're also assuming that the dates are in the same month, and you're using deprecated methods of `Date`.

Given these problems, you'd be *much* better off using `LocalDate` either from [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) if you're using Java 7 or earlier, or from `java.time` if you're using Java 8.

`LocalDate` is immutable, so it's harder to accidentally end up adding the same reference multiple times - and it really represents *just a date*.